# Reshape multi-temporal, mutlispectral 3D numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm working with multi-temporal, multispectral satellite imagery. The data are stored as geotiffs in the shape `((n_bands x n_timesteps), height, width)`. I need to reshape the array for ML model training where each pixel in the image is a "sample". The training array would therefore be shape `(n_samples x n_timesteps x n_bands)`.

Assume the following array and associated variables. Also assume the number of bands in the dataset is 12 and the number if time steps is 4. Therefore, the first dimension of the array is 12*4 = 48.

```
x = np.random.rand(48, 512, 512)

width = x.shape[1]
height = x.shape[2]
n_samples = width * height

n_bands = 12
n_timesteps = x.shape[0] / n_bands
```

What is the best way to reshape the array `x` to `x_reshape` such that `x_reshape.shape` returns:

```
(n_samples, n_timesteps, n_bands)
```

Making sure to preserve the correct ordering of the data such that a slice of `x_reshape[0]` is a single "sample" of the dataset of shape `(n_timesteps x n_features)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy.reshape()` and after that `numpy.moveaxis()` to achieve what you want:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(48, 512, 512)

width = x.shape[1]
height = x.shape[2]
n_samples = width * height

n_bands = 12
n_timesteps = int(x.shape[0] / n_bands)

x = np.reshape(x, (n_timesteps,n_bands,n_samples))
x = np.moveaxis(x, -1, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you this is super close but give shape (n_samples, n_bands, n_timesteps) rather than (n_samples, n_timesteps, n_bands). Can I change the last line - np.moveaxis(x, -1, 0) to np.swapaxes(x, -1, 0), which gives x.shape = (262144, 4, 12) and assume the data are correctly aligned?

Comment: Sorry. My bad. I edited the code. I changed the order of dimensions in reshape.